# How can I add new words in wordnet dictionary?

Tags: python, wordnet, sentence-similarity

I am trying to match two sentences and find similarities.

Seems like some of the word (Noun) from my sentence are not present in wordnet dictionary. How can I add them in wordnet?

Comment: The database is in plaintext ASCII according to https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/database/ , so you could edit the database using a text editor like Notepad++. The link describes the necessary format for each word in the dictionary.

Comment: @BennettBrown that sounds like a decent answer, if you post the format in the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/extjwnl/

> extJWNL (Extended Java WordNet Library) is a Java API for creating, reading and updating dictionaries in WordNet format. extJWNL is an upgraded version of JWNL. The library features support for creating, editing and writing dictionaries; dictionary encodings, including UTF-8; Java generics; huge dictionaries; instance dictionaries and static singletone dictionary; Maven and more.

An example script, for adding a new sense is at https://github.com/extjwnl/extjwnl/wiki/ewnUserManual#script-editing

```
goal%1:09:00:: -add -addword end -setgloss "the state of affairs that a plan ... achieve it; ""the ends justify the means"""
goal%1:09:00:: -addptr content%1:09:00:: @
n#oxen -addexc ox
```

Which is then run with `ewn -script filename`